# Jquery hover fade thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, thumbnails

I am trying to create some jquery styled hover fade in/out thumbnails. I've managed to do the hover in and out on the images but theres a problem. As the user hovers over, I want some text to appear, which I have achieved with CSS, the problem is, when the user hovers over the text the image fades back in. I was wondering how I could make it so the image continues to stay faded out whilst also hovering over the text. I do not want the text to become faded either, I have tried simply switching to the thumb class in the script section.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumb img").fadeTo("fast", 1.0); // This sets the opacity of the thumbs to fade down to 60% when the page loads

    $(".thumb img").hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3); // This should set the opacity to 100% on hover
    },function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0); // This should set the opacity back to 60% on mouseout
    });


});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="thumb">
 <a href="#"><img src="images/hooty_thumb.png" width="250" height="224"/></a>
 <div class="title">
<h1 class="din"><a href="#">TITLE HERE</a></h1>
<h2><a href="#">Branding, Print, Web</a></h2>
<h2><a href="#">2011</a></h2></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb {float: left; background-color: #FFF; z-index: 1; width: 250px; height: 225px; margin-right: 27px; margin-bottom: 45px; display: inline-block; *display:inline; *zoom: 1; position: relative;}
.thumb .title{position:absolute; width: 250px;  top: 40%; left:0%; text-align: center; display: none; z-index: -1;}
.thumb:hover .title{display: inline; z-index: 1;}
.thumb .title h1{color:#00F;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,  You needed to go up one level and attach the rollover events to the parent then traverse the DOM to the image and set its opacity.  *Side Note $(document).ready(function(){ }) is same as $(function(){ })

```
$(function(){
    $(".thumb img").fadeTo("fast", 1.0); 

    $(".thumb").bind({
        mouseenter:function(){
            $('img', this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
        },mouseleave: function(){
            $('img', this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With the same HTML and CSS, I adjusts you event bind from `thumb img` to `thumb` to ensure the event happens on the whole image block. With in the event callback, I used a [jQuery context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) to detect the `img` element and perform fade-in / fade-out effect on it.

The effect could be seen here. http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/5pnQA/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumb img").fadeTo("fast", 1.0); // This sets the opacity of the thumbs to fade down to 60% when the page loads
    $(".thumb").hover(function() {
        $('img', this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3); // This should set the opacity to 100% on hover
    }, function() {
        $('img', this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0); // This should set the opacity back to 60% on mouseout
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this with Html and CSS only, your page will be more efficient.
**Html5**

```
<a href="#" class="thumb">
    <img src="images/hooty_thumb.png" width="250" height="224"/>
    <strong>TITLE HERE</strong>
    <em>Branding, Print, Web</em>
    <time>2011</time>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a.thumb{float:left; position:relative; background:#FFF; z-index:1; width:250px; height:225px; text-decoration:none; margin:0 27px 45px;}
a.thumb img{opacity:0.6; -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s linear; -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s linear;}
a.thumb:hover img{opacity:1;}
a.thumb>strong, .thumb>em, .thumb>time{opacity:0; -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s linear; -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s linear;}
a.thumb:hover>strong, .thumb:hover>em, .thumb:hover>time{opacity:1;}
```

Comment: The only problem is with this is that when I add my centered code to center the text in the middle, all of the em, strong etc. overlap each other, is there a way to solve this? Also webkit only works with safari and chrome doesn't it?